# Looping through RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, webforms

I am creating a site that contains 3 surveys stored in one SQL table, so based on the selected SurveyID the page will then be populated by the Questions and an answer line, now I have achieved this but now I need to be able to retrieve the information.

Using a DataList, each question generates a line, and within the itemtemplate of my DataList (QuestionList) I have put the following:

```
<asp:DataList ID="QuestionList" runat="server" DataKeyField="QuestionID" DataSourceID="QuestionData">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-12" id="hr">
            <h3>
                <asp:Label ID="Higher_ReadingLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Higher_Reading") %>' /></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" id="lr">
            <h3>
                <asp:Label ID="Lower_ReadingLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Lower_Reading") %>' /></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="AnswerList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Excellent" Value="Excellent"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Very Good" Value="Very Good"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Good" Value="Good"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Fair" Value="Fair"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Bad" Value="Bad"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

When the submit button is clicked, I want to retrieve the following:

- DataKeyField of the QuestionList
- Value of Checked Radio Button within AnswerList

I admit I am pretty stumped atm, everything I have tried hasnt worked at all, as the SQL isnt wrote yet I just wanted to see if the output could just output using Response.Write(value,datakeyfield).

Hope you guys can help,

Neil

Comment: can u share more code of datalist

Comment: I have just amended it to add more detail

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpfull for you:

```
foreach (DataListItem datalistItem in QuestionList.Items)
        {
            if (datalistItem.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || datalistItem.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                var radioButtonList = datalistItem.FindControl("AnswerList") as RadioButtonList;
                if (radioButtonList != null)
                {
                    var selectedRadioButtonValue = radioButtonList.SelectedValue;
                    var itemDataKeyValue = QuestionList.DataKeys[datalistItem.ItemIndex];
                    Response.Write(string.Format("QuestionID :{0}, selected option: {1} <br/>", itemDataKeyValue, selectedRadioButtonValue));
                }
            }
        }
```